# In views.py ### category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category = cat) ### RETURNS AN EMPTY QUERY SET

Tags: django, web-development-server

I am creating a blog application in django where i encountered this unusual issue. I am not being able to filter and display blog posts category wise. Please find my code below. Thanks in advance.

#### MODELS.py

This is the model which i have created for a blog post.

```
class Post(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    author = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    body = models.TextField()
    post_date = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=255, default="uncategorized")

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title + ' | ' + str(self.author)

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        #return reverse('article-detail', args=(str(self.id)))
        return reverse('homepage')
```

#### VIEWS.py

This is the view that i have created for a category wise blog posts.

```
def CategoryView(request,cats):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(author= 'apaar')
    return render(request,'categories.html',{'cat':cat,'category_posts':category_posts})
```

#### URLS.py

The urls.py file.

```
    path('category/<str:cat>/', CategoryView, name = 'category'),
```

#### CATEGORIES.html

This will be the final display page where the category_posts is displayed as an empty queryset. The for loop is unable to run because category_posts is an empty queryset.

```
{% extends 'base.html' %}
{% load static %}

{% block content %}
<h1>Categories</h1>
<ul>
{% for posts in category_posts %}
<li>
    <div class="category"><a href="{% url 'category' post.category|slugify %}">{{ post.category }}</a></div>
    <a href="{% url 'article-detail' post.pk  %}"><h3><b>{{ post.title }} </b></h3>

    <p class=card-date>    <big>{{ post.author }}</big><small> -{{ post.post_date }}     </small> </p>
    <p class="excerpt-text">{{ post.body | slice:"100" |safe}}</p>

    <div class="article-thumbnail">
      <img src="{% static "images/bg.png" %}" alt="article-thumbnail" >
    <div class="overlay"></a>
</li>
{% endfor %}

{% endblock %}
```

Comment: Likely because you slugify the category, and hence it no longer matches with the real category.

Comment: I think you made a typo in your template codes... change `posts` to `post` in your for loop.. (i.e. `{% for posts in category_posts %}` to `{% for post in category_posts %}`)

Comment: First off, Willem Van Onsem Roham Slavi Thanks for taking to time to help me out with my query. @Slavi: Initially, I used (category=cat) to filter them but i got the same empty query set. Then, just to try things out i changed it to author just to see if i get any data. but both ways i'm getting an empty query set. and i did try {% for post in category_posts %} . the for loop is not running only as there is nothing in category_posts. I tried categories single word categories also that do not require slugify, still no luck. So i doubt if its a slugify issue.

Answer (score 0):

By what I understand you're trying to do you want the following:

```
def CategoryView(request,cat):
    category_posts = Post.objects.filter(category=cat)
    return render(request,'categories.html',{'category_posts':category_posts})
```

Use `cat` as your parameter, since you're using `<str:cat>` in your urls.py, otherwise you might get an "Unexpected parameter" error.
You have to filter by `category`, not `author`. Youre question is correct, but your code isn't.
You don't need to pass cat varibale in context, since any posts would contain it within themselves.

Taking @Willem Van Onsem and @Roham suggestions:

```
{% for post in category_posts %}
# ...
    <div class="category"><a href="{% url 'category' post.category    %}">{{ post.category }}</a></div>
```

If you want to use slugs, maybe checkout `models.SlugField`.

Comment: First off, Willem Van Onsem Roham Slavi Thanks for taking to time to help me out with my query.

@Slavi: Initially, I used (category=cat) to filter them but i got the same empty query set. Then, just to try things out i changed it to author just to see if i get any data. but both ways i'm getting an empty query set. 

and i did try {% for post in category_posts %} . the for loop is not running only as there is nothing in category_posts.
I tried categories single word categories also that do not require slugify, still no luck. So i doubt if its a slugify issue.

Comment: @Apaar Make sure that `Post.objects.filter(category='enter_a_valid_category')` returns a non-empty query-set (you can do this in the shell).

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help. turns out it was a slugify issue so i got rid of it. Did this instead  to get rid of %20 : cat = cat.replace("%20", " ") and cat = cat.replace("+", " ")